# Cant open a url in browser using webbrowser library in python

Tags: python, browser, python-webbrowser

I tried to open `google.com` using these codes below

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new_tab('google.com')
```

I ran codes above on my visual studio code console and it didnt launch the browser, then  I tried
to change the current working directory to the python folder path, and it worked.
But my question is can i open the url without changing the working directory?

Comment: try giving the full url like "www.google.com"

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. Do you get any errors when "it didn't launch the browser"?